# Receiving UDP packet without IP address

Tags: python, sockets, ip, dhcp

I'm trying to implement simple DHCP client. The problem is receiving UDP broadcast packets on network interface that hasn't assigned ip address yet.
I think I can simplify my issue to following scripts that I execute in docker containers working in the same bridge network.

sender.py:

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "255.255.255.255"
UDP_PORT = 5005
MESSAGE = b"Hello, World!"

print("UDP target IP: %s" % UDP_IP)
print("UDP target port: %s" % UDP_PORT)
print("message: %s" % MESSAGE)

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP

sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, 25, str(f"eth1" + '\0').encode('utf-8'))
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

receiver.py:

```
import socket

UDP_IP = ""
UDP_PORT = 5005

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, 25, str(f"eth1" + '\0').encode('utf-8'))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    print("received message: %s" % data)
```

If i execute upper scripts when ip address is statically assigned to eth1- interface (172.1.2.2) i receive packet. But after deleting ip address:

```
ip addr del 172.1.2.2/24 dev eth1
```

I can't receive anything.
Of course i can observe sent packet on eth1 on receiver side by tcpdump.

How can i receive UDP broadcast packet, on interface that doesn't have assigned ip address ?

Comment: Have you tried UDP_IP = '0.0.0.0' (on the receiver side)?

Comment: @MatíasSanturio binding to `""` is the same as binding to `'0.0.0.0'`